# Python, wxPython: Get result of script in different directory

Tags: python, wxpython, wxglade

sorry for my English, but is not my native language.

I made a python script that works like this:

```
python procesamiento.py Excel1
```

`Excel1` is a string to a excel file in a different directory of my script.
When I run the script, the result is another excel file, `excelprocesado.xls`, generated in the directory where the script is. How do I get `excelprocesado.xls` is generated in the directory where `Excel1` is?
I'm working with wxpython and wxGlade to get the path of `Excel1`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `os.path.basedir(myFile)` ? its unfortunately not very clear what you are trying to do and whats wrong with it currently ...

Comment: You will most likely need to edit `procesamiento.py` to make it behave the way you want. To make it the most flexible, I would add some command line arguments to the script so you can specify an output directory. You can use Python's `argparse` module for that.